Polynomial Approximation of Piecewise Continuous Functions
I'm looking for results about constructing polynomial approximations of piecewise continuous functions. Specifically, I'm wondering about whether there is a straightforward approach to the following problem:
Let $f(x)$ be a continuously differentiable function on a closed interval $[a, d]$, and let $b, c\in [a, d]$ with $a < b < c < d$. Then, define $g(x)$ on $[a, d]$ as
\begin{align}
g(x) & = \begin{cases}
f(x), & a \leq x < b \\
C, & b \leq x < c \\
f(x), & c \leq x, \leq d
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $C \in \mathbb{R}$ is some constant.
Let's say there exists a polynomial approximation of $f$ with finitely many terms $f(x) \approx \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha_n x^n$ and bounded error $\epsilon(N) = |f(x) - \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \alpha_n x^n|^2_2$ (as a function of the number of polynomial terms $N$). What can we say about a polynomial approximation of $g$? Does such an approximation exist? Is it related to the approximation of $f$? Does it need more terms than the approximation of $f$?
My thought is that we can approximate a piecewise continuous function like $g$ with the Fourier series, but this is not a polynomial approximation and we may see Gibbs phenomena at the points of discontinuity. Thank you!

Is what you want the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernstein_polynomial s? Also see the Weierstrass approximation theorem.

@person, I don't see mention of discontinuous or piecewise continuous function approximation on that page. Similarly, I believe the Weierstrauss approximation theorem only applies to continuous functions on a closed interval.

Oh I misinterpreted what you meant by piecewise continuous. In this case, you can still do this combined with your comment. Approximate your function by a Fourier series (the Fejer kernel version, not the Dirichlet kernel version, this gets rid of the Gibbs phenomenon), and then approximate that by polynomials. You obviously cannot hope to approximate your discontinuous function uniformly since it is discontinuous, best you can hope for is $L^p$ approximation. See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%2527s_theorem

@person Thank you! This is helpful. I am looking only for $L^p$ approximation anyways, probably should have said that in the post. The way you suggest ($g(x) \to$ Fourier series $\to$ polynomials) is there a straightforward way to estimate the $L^p$ approximation error as a function of the number of polynomial terms in the approximation?

Probably not, and if it exists, its probably highly dependent on your way of approximating. The Wikipedia page for Bernstein polynomials has a proof of the Weierstrass approximation theorem that can be easily modified to give convergence rates in terms of the modulus of continuity of your $f$. But as far as I know off the top of my head I can’t remember many numerically robust ways of estimating rate of convergence for Fourier series.
